# Auto Complete does not filter results when I'm typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have very simple form that gets values in JSON format from `searchAlbum.php`. It works when I start typing something in, but it does not filter results, for example it shows `123` as available even though I typed `ab`.

This is what my `saerchAlbum.php` is returning

```
["123","abc"]
```

This is my Java Script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.albumName').autocomplete({
                    source: 'searchAlbum.php'
                });
});
```

You might say that it should not filter my resoulds and I need to pass my input as a paramater but why then [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) examle on jquery-ui page does that for me?

Comment: Have you considered that it's a problem with the server side code, and not the jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation isn't clear about it, but the only time the autocompleter does the filtering for you is when your code isn't getting called at all (e.g., you've given it an array as `source`). When your code is getting called (either client-side code because you've given a function for `source`, or server-side code because you've given a URL), your code is expected to do the filtering.

> You might say that it should not filter my resoulds and I need to pass my input as a paramater but why then this examle on jquery-ui page does that for me?

Because the `search.php` page that the example calls filters the results based on the `term` parameter the autocompleter passes it. Compare the results you get from these:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=ti

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=ro

You can see that it's filtering server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The js sends a query string parameter named "term", your php code needs to return data by filtering existing data that match the "term" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Javascript or jQuery problem, but a PHP problem.  As mentioned in the linked jQuery-UI page, the source script must process the "term" property via a GET request.